# Ubuntu / Apache does not want to download txt file

Tags: 14.04

I have a website (apache2, php5, mysql) installed on Ubuntu VPS. When you load the web .txt file does not download but just look, do not know how to do to, for example, when I go to localhost / myfile.txt so instead of a text file to download are only displayed. I need to txt file automatically downloaded to the PC.

Comment: I solved it.
Here you have the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310453/button-to-download-txt-file-php-html